# Could not find load main class GridLauncher for selendroid grid

Tags: android, selenium, automated-tests, selendroid

I want to test my native android app parallelly using Selenium grid .Is there any option to do the same in Selenium grid or in selendroid.

I tried steps mentioned in selendroid.io/scale.html and i encounter below mentioned error.
**Error**

> D:\mobile-test\selendroid grid>java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp
>   "selendroid-grid-plugin-0.17.0.jar:selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar"
>   org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher -capabilityMatcher
>   io.selendroid.grid.SelendroidCapabilityMatcher -role hub -host
>   127.0.0.1 -port 4444 Error: Could not find or load main class org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher

Comment: Yes you can test all **native**,**web**,**hybrid** apps with selendroid grid. Have a look at :[Selendroid Scalling](http://selendroid.io/scale.html).

Comment: BTW if you have already gone through procedure, are you facing any issue?

Comment: Yes i got an error:Error: Could not find or load main class org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher

Comment: D:\mobile-test\selendroid grid>java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp "selendroid-grid-plugin-0.17.0.jar;selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar" org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher -capabilityMatcher
 io.selendroid.grid.SelendroidCapabilityMatcher -role hub -host 127.0.0.1 -port 4444
Error: Could not find or load main class org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher

Comment: You mean we can test native app in parallel or simultaneously using Selenium grid

Comment: You can add your mobile device having any type of android app to already established grid. Grid is not launching has nothing to do with type of app you are testing.

Comment: Have you launched your selenium-standalone server first? before starting the grid plugin?

Comment: Yes . I have done that .

Comment: java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp "selendroid-grid-plugin-0.17.0.jar:selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar" org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher -capabilityMatcher
 io.selendroid.grid.SelendroidCapabilityMatcher -role hub -host 127.0.0.1 -port 4444

Comment: I have used above mentioned comment

Comment: @mk08 I have tried with different versions of selendroid-grid-plugin and selenium-server-standalone but showing same error .

Comment: Let me try on my side. I used Appium to deal with android / iOS apps for automation testing. Hence I am sure you can connect mobile to grid.

Comment: Are you on windows? watch out for `:` in class path command. Windows use `;` to separate out multiple jars in classpath.

Comment: Yeah I could launch the selendroid grid with `D:\>java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp "selendroid-grid-plugin-0.17.0.jar;selenium-s
erver-standalone-2.46.0.jar" org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher -capabilityMatcher io.selendroid.grid.SelendroidCapabilityMatcher -role hub -host 127.0.0.1 -port 4444`

Comment: @mk08 thanks a lot it worked for me .

Comment: Great! Were you missing semi-Colan?

Comment: Yes was trying with  : instead of semicolon

Comment: @mk08 Can you please write your mentioned solution as answer.So that it may help others too.

Comment: You may want to change the question statement, as the answer you got after lot of discussion in comments.

Comment: :) Solution I gave, is not following the question you asked. You can change the question something like `Could not find load main class GridLauncher for selendroid grid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is with Jar file separator. If you are working on *Mac/Unix* use path separator as colon `:`. If you are working on `Windows` then use path separator as semicolon `;`.

The exact usage is given on [Selendroid Scaling](http://selendroid.io/scale.html). But it is very easy to miss out. You will not get any direct error for using wrong path separator but will end up getting `ClassNotFoundError` or similar.