# Could not find or load main class org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3 - Grid Extras

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am trying to add custom servlets to my selenium Grid using the latest version of selenium server. I have done this with older version and it was working. Now they have made changes and removed deprecated classes. 
As per the Grid documentation provided (https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp#starting-selenium-grid) , i have created one simple java project with some extra capabilities(Extended RegistryBasedServlet). After creating the extras jar, i am trying to start Selenium Server with custom servlets class and it is throwing "Could not find or load main class org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3" error. If i start selenium server without custom servlets, server is starting without any problem.

I am using selenium server 3.11.0 (http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=3.11/) & jdk 1.8

Command ( with custom Servlets):

```
java -cp selenium-server-standalone.jar:grid-extras.jar org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3 \ -servlets com.shc.selenium.grid.hub.Console -role hub
```

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/33951046/5155484

Comment: I had the same error on Ubuntu when using a file and script on a smb mount.